# Как сделать перевод цен из админки WP в выбранной валюте в рубли для клиента?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Делаю сайт и требуется чтобы администратор в карточке товара мог выбирать валюту цены товара. К примеру устанавливает цену в 10$, а сам пользователь на сайте видел уже 800р.
Нашел плагин WBW Currency Switcher for WooCommerce. Там я установил доллар основной валютой и на сайте появляется цена = цена в админке * 80(курс доллара к рублю). Но как сделать эту основную валюту динамической и редактируемой?
Я в самом php слаб, может можно поменять через js?